# Why $\varepsilon \colon kG \to k$ is called the augmentation map?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory, terminology

For the group algebra $kG$ of a finite group $G$ over a field $k$,
a $k$-linear map $\varepsilon \colon kG \to k$ defined by
$$ \varepsilon\left(\sum_{g \in G}c_g g\right) = \sum_{g \in G}c_g $$
is called the augmentation map (and $\ker \varepsilon$ is called the augmentation ideal).

I don't have any idea that what the augmentation map *augments* (makes greater or increases). Why $\varepsilon \colon kG \to k$ is called the augmentation map?

Comment: I would guess it comes from algebraic topology, where such a map is used to obtain reduced (co)homology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_homology

Comment: @JefLaga So the augmentation map in such a context simply augments a chain complex by adding an extra term $\mathbb{Z}$? Or is there some topological intuition behind? And the similarity to the group theoretic context is just the defining equation (and thus $\varepsilon \colon kG \to k$ augments nothing)?

Comment: An algebra is just an algebra. An algebra with an additional special map has been augmented by associating an additional map with the algebra. The map is an extra datum for the algebra, so the algebra has *been augmented* by it.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, such an explanation is certainly true. But it's almost independent from the specific context here and hence can be applied to anything other than this.

Comment: @Orat I understand what one would be hesitant to consider it, but I think it might just be that simple. Similar to the category of [pointed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set), or rings with involution.

Comment: I think this comes from the terminology of monoidal category. where k serves as the monoidal counit I. Counterintuitively, the augmentation map e: X --> I in computer science stands for deletion of data!

Comment: @Coward Interesting. I guess, however, the term augmentation for group algebras appeared preceding in time than that for monoidal categories. If it were true, then such can't be a historical explanation and things go the other way around.